# Linked List selection sort implementation performance issue?

Tags: python, linked-list, selection-sort

I've developed the below code, but I'm seeing some unusual behavior which I'm struggling to understand:

```py
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None

    def get_data(self):
        return self.val

    def set_data(self,val):
        self.val = val

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next

    def set_next(self,next):
        self.next = next


class LinkedList(object):        

    def __init__(self,*values):
        self.count = len(values) -1
        self.head = Node(values[0])
        node = self.head
        for idx, val in enumerate(values):
            if idx == 0:
                continue
            else:
                tempnode = Node(val)
                node.set_next(tempnode)
                node = node.get_next()


    def get_count(self):
        return self.head

    def insert(self,data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node
        self.count +=1

    def insert_at(self,idx,val):
        if idx > self.count +2:
            return

        if idx == 0:
            self.insert(val)
        else:
            tempIdx = 0
            node = self.head
            while tempIdx < idx -1:
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx += 1
            continuation = node.get_next()
            insertion = Node(val)
            node.set_next(insertion)
            node.get_next().set_next(continuation)

    def find(self,val):
        item = self.head
        while item != None:
            if item.get_data() == val:
                return item
            else:
                item = item.get_next()

        return None

    def deleteAt(self,idx):
        if idx > self.count+1:
            return
        if idx == 0:
            self.head = self.head.get_next()
        else:
            tempIdx = 0
            node = self.head
            while tempIdx < idx -1:
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx +=1
            node.set_next(node.get_next().get_next())
            self.count -= 1

    def dump_list(self):
        tempnode = self.head
        while (tempnode != None):
            print("Node: ",tempnode.get_data())
            tempnode = tempnode.get_next()       


    def swap(self,idx_a,idx_b):
        if idx_a == idx_b:
            return
        elif idx_a > idx_b:
            idx_2,idx_1 = idx_a,idx_b
        else:
            idx_2,idx_1 = idx_b,idx_a

        node = self.head
        tempIdx = 0

        while tempIdx < idx_2:
            if tempIdx != idx_1:
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx += 1
            else:
                elem_1 = node.get_data()
                node = node.get_next()
                tempIdx += 1
        elem_2 = node.get_data()

        self.deleteAt(idx_1)
        self.deleteAt(idx_2-1)
        self.insert_at(idx_1,elem_2)
        self.insert_at(idx_2,elem_1)

    def move_min(self,sorted_idx):
        temp_idx = 0
        node = self.head
        while temp_idx <= self.count:

            if temp_idx <= sorted_idx:
                node = node.get_next()
                temp_idx += 1

            elif temp_idx == sorted_idx +1:
                selection = node.get_data()
                selected_idx = temp_idx
                node = node.get_next()
                temp_idx += 1

            else:
                if node.get_data() < selection:
                    selection = node.get_data()
                    selected_idx = temp_idx
                try:
                    node = node.get_next()
                    temp_idx +=1
                except:
                    break

        self.deleteAt(selected_idx)
        self.insert_at(sorted_idx, selection)
        return sorted_idx + 1  

    def selection_sort(self):
        sorted_idx = 0
        while sorted_idx < self.count +1:
            sorted_idx = self.move_min(sorted_idx)
```

Now, I use selection sort on the following linked list

```py
t1 = LinkedList(4,3,2,1,0)
t1.selection_sort()
t1.dump_list()

>>>>
Node:  0
Node:  1
Node:  3
Node:  4
Node:  2
```

The selection sort method simply calls move_min method until the sorted_idx reaches the length of the LL. So I gather the problem must involve the move_min function.

The general flow is: Skip past all the sorted portion of the LL as captured by the variable `sorted_idx` Then set the `selection` as the following node's value. After this point, if any node has a lower value then selection, selection's value is replaced. After the loop has finished the minimum value will be moved from its current location to the sorted_idx location. Lastly the sorted_idx will be incremented by 1 and returned.

The selection_sort method uses the returned value above as the sorted_idx in each iteration.

I'm really not sure where I'm going wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually being caused by a flaw in your `insert_at` member. `deleteAt` decrements `count`, but `insert_at` can potentially never call `insert` to increment it. This leads to your loop in `selection_sort` exiting prematurely because you're doing an insert/delete to emulate a swap. The fix for this should be to correctly increment `count` for any successful insert.

Comment: I would never have caught that. Thank you!